# how to loop over JSON array in angular

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a `JSON array` in my `CI` view like

```
<?php $columns = [".","Product Name","Subtracking","Sale Amount","Merchant Sale Amount","AN","Advertiser Name"," Date "]?>
```

I want to set these as my `ng-grid` header
I have tried the following but did not work for me

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'myData',
            columnDefs: <?php echo $columns?>
        };
```

Comment: How are you planning to write php code in javascript file?

Comment: its like file is being uploaded and after reading that file and converting it to array, i am separating the 1st index of that array as there are column headings in that array

Comment: I mean to say, Php doesn't work in `.js` files

Comment: i have included this `JS` in my php file, and its working if i do `console.log(<?php echo $column?>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array, use this syntax for looping over it

`<div ng-repeat="col in gridOptions.columnDefs">{{col}}</div>`

for more info read this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

**Edit:** Is this what you want http://plnkr.co/edit/LIAqMq4TEz9xOCUGPAUs?p=preview

Comment: this just repeats the columns array, i need to set this array as col header :(

Comment: check the plunkr link i just added

Comment: yeah exactly, but `columns` might be changed, how i can achieve this?

Comment: You are already doing it using `<?php echo $columns?>`, whatever it returns will be set here and if the data changes columns change automatically in angularJs. What exactly do you want? you should be clear about that in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to do something like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'myData',
            columnDefs: <?php echo json_encode($columns) ?>
        };
```

Just to ensure that you're actually passing valid JSON to the JS file. Hope that helps.

Comment: this is already done in `PHP`, i have converted the array to `JSON` and `$columns` in my code is the output of that `JSON array`